# How to implement Repeated alert sound notification in flutter Timer app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, timer, flutter-local-notification

I've been developing my very first **timer app**, and now it kinda work both in **iOS** and **android** platform.

When the time's up, I use **flutter_local_notification** to play alert and sound. But it the sound doesn't repeat as the actual timer app. **It only plays once and dismisses.**

I would like to implement like ***the sound keep repeating*** until the user click something in the notification.

Is there any way we can do it in flutter?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?